# How to Create Save and Read Xml file in j2me

Tags: xml, java-me

I need to create xml file in j2me and save this file to phone 
and also read the xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this tutorial link for reading/writing concepts are same in java/java-me

http://www.roseindia.net/xml/dom/CreatXMLFile.shtml

http://www.javazoom.net/services/newsletter/xmlgeneration.html

http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaXML/article.html